# Prove that if C is a closed set and $L = sup (C)$, then $L \in C$.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if C is a closed set and $L = sup (C)$, then $L \in C$

This is what I have in mind, but I am not sure if it is quite right.

Proof:

Assume $L \notin C$, then $L \in C'$. 
Since C is closed, C' is open.
And also $L = sup(C)$, therefore, $\forall a \in C, a \le L$.

Then L is less than or equal to b for all $b \in C'$.

Therefore, L is a lower bound of C'.

Moreover, since $L \in C'$ and $\forall b\in C', L \le b$,
if there is $M \le L$, then $M \notin C'$.

Thus, $L = inf(C')$.

Since C' is open, $\exists r \gt 0$ such that $(L-r, L+r) \subset C'$.
Then $\exists b \in C'$ such that $ L-r \lt b \lt L+r$.
Since $b \in C'$, $L \le b $, $ L-r \le b-r$
but $(L-r, L+r) \subset C'$ and $ L-r\le b-r \lt b$, thus $b-r \in C'$.

Now, $b \lt L+r$, $b-r \lt L$ but $b -r \in C' $; this contradict the fact that L is infimum of C'. Therefore, $L \notin C'$.
Then, $L \in C$.

Comment: There is always a sequence of points of $C$ that converge to $L$. Since $C$ is closed...

Comment: I'm okay with this proof, even if adding a few explanations to conclude on the last paragraph would be great.

Comment: $L$ need not be the infimum of the complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $L = \sup(C)$, where $C$ is non-empty in some ordered space $(X,<)$ in the order topology. In particular this works in the real line in its usual topology.

If $L = \max(X)$ (it it exists), then a (standard) basic neighbourhood $O$ of $L$ looks like $O = (a,L]$, where $a \in X$, otherwise it's of the form $O = (a,b)$ with $a < L < b$.

In either case, as $a$ is strictly smaller than $L$, it cannot be an upperbound for $C$ (as the supremum is the smallest upperbound). So for some $c \in C$ we have $a > c$, and as $c \in C$ we have $c \le L$, as $L$ is an upperbound for $C$.

So $c \in O$, whatever the form of $O$ was. As $O$ was an arbitrary neighbourhood of $L$, $L \in \overline{C}$. In particular, if $C$ was closed, $L \in C$.